# sprite plugin for gulp#4.0

Tags: gulp, спрайт

Друзья, помогите, не могу настроить сборку спрайтов(изображения) для gulp. Ставил плагин gulp.spritesmith и gupl-spritesmith - они выдают ошибку:

```
invalid file signature
```

Я предполагаю, что это из-за версии gulp#4.0.

Собственно вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста плагин создания спрайтов для 4 версии gulp или возможно кто-то знает как устранить эту ошибку?

код с плагином gulp.spritesmith:

```
var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');

gulp.task('sprite', function() {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('./source/sprite/*.png')
    .pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.png',
    imgPath: './build/pictures/sprite.png',
    cssName: '_sprite.css',
    padding: 5
  }));

  spriteData.img
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/pictures'));

  spriteData.css
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./source/scss'));
});
```

Comment: почему не использовать на время 3 пока 4 в beta

Comment: Есть зависимости от 4